# Is it possible to prevent LocatorPane from modifying locator positions unless Alt ket is down?

Tags: dynamic, locator, eventhandler

I am using the `LocatorAutoCreate` option which allows the user to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking in order to create/remove locators. However, I need to be able to prevent the "original" functionality of `LocatorPane` which moves the closest locator to the current mouse position whenever you click.

To clarify, I will use a simple example:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[list], Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], LocatorAutoCreate -> True]
```

I want to prevent locators from being moved when clicking and not holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but still keep the functionality of `LocatorAutoCreate` which creates/removes the locators when the user holds <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicks.

My guess is that I will need to use some combination of `EventHandler`, `DynamicWrapper`, and `CurrentValue`, but I am not experienced with these functions and have not yet been able to find a solution.

My best idea currently is to use something like this:

```
DynamicWrapper[
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[list], Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}], LocatorAutoCreate -> True],
  If[CurrentValue["MouseButtonTest"] && ! CurrentValue["AltKey"], 
    CurrentValue["MouseButtonTest"] = False]]
```

Yet, clearly this doesn't work as you cannot manually set CurrentValue["MouseButtonTest"] to False.

#### Edit

A few minutes after making this post I thought of a solution (even though I had spent 2 hours prior struggling). If anyone is curious, this problem can be solved using the second argument of dynamic:

```
LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[list, 
    (If[CurrentValue["MouseButtonTest"] && ! CurrentValue["AltKey"], 
       list = list, list = #]) &],
  Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}],
  LocatorAutoCreate -> True]
```

Comment: You should remove your edit post as a self-answer.

Comment: I am not sure I got it, so the only action allowed is locators creation right? They should always stay whey they were created?

Comment: LocatorAutoCreate also allows the user to click on a selected locator while holding alt to remove it. So the user can remove a locator and  then create a new locator in the necessary position to "move" it.